# C programming: reading and writing binary files

Tags: c, file, fopen, binaryfiles, strtok

I apologise if this has been asked and answered, but I couldn't find any topics with good responses that applied specifically to C (rather than C++).

I want to read from (and write to) a binary file with a user-input filename. I also want to use a specific format for the header of the file, as shown below.

```
typedef struct binary_file {
    uint32_t user_id;
    uint16_t age;
};
```

But... I just can't get it to work! And I don't know what's what's going wrong. Here is my attempt at opening the file.

```
char *token;
char input[MAX_LINE]

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    while (fgets(input, MAX_LINE, stdin)!=NULL) {
        token = strtok(input, " \n");
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (token != NULL) {
            bin_name = token;
            FILE * the_file
            the_file = fopen(bin_name, "rb");
            if (the_file == NULL) {
                printf("file not found");
            }
            else {
                printf("file found");
                fclose(the_file);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've also tried using sys/stat.h to check if the file exists, but both come back with no (binary) file any time. What am I doing wrong?

Moreso, how on earth do I go about creating my own binary file using this structure!? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: it doesn't even compile, missing semicolon...

Comment: Where are your variables declared? Are they *all* global? What are you trying to accomplish with `strtok`? What sort of input are you expecting?

Comment: Apologies, I have tried my best to fix the compile errors (and included the *token and input variables).
At the moment, I am just trying to receive user input until a valid file has been loaded.

Comment: `file not found` is a completely useless error message if the actual problem is something else (eg, permissions).  Try `if (the_file == NULL) { perror(bin_name);}`

Answer (score 1):

Your `bin_name` is NULL, since it was assigned from `token`, which was NULL. Hence, `fopen(bin_name, "rb")` crashes.

As for where to start, I highly recommend *The C Programming Language*, 2nd ed., by the language designers Kernighan and Ritchie.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. In my code I had actually set it to if (token != NULL) but made a typo when uploading it.

Comment: @DifficultTangerine, "In my actual code I had set it [...]" is not a response that bodes well for this question.  If you want answers that are actually helpful, then we need you to present a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  You cannot expect to arrive at one by carelessly trimming code out of your program.  Before you post it, make sure it compiles, and that when it runs it exhibits the same problem as the original.  Ideally, you would use a debugger to verify that the problem is really the same.